# How can I know that IDBCursor reached it's last value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, indexeddb

I tried to promisify `IDBCursor`, like that:

```
/**
 * @description Allows asynchronous looping over IDBCursor. The cursor request must be provided and must be new and unused!
 */
class IndexedDBAsyncCursor {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {IndexedDBAsyncTable} parentTable
     * @param {IDBRequest} cursorRequest
     */
    constructor(parentTable, cursorRequest) {
        this.cursorRequest = cursorRequest;

        this.table = parentTable;
        /** @type {Promise<IDBCursor>} **/
        this.nextValuePromise = null;
        /** @type {IDBCursor} **/
        this.lastCursor = null;

        this.hasNext = true;

        this.hookCursorRequest();
    }
    /**
     * @description Starts waiting for the next value
     * @private
     */
    makeNextValuePromise() {
        if (this.nextValuePromise == null) {
            this.rejectPromise = null;
            this.resolvePromise =null;
            this.nextValuePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.rejectPromise = reject;
                this.resolvePromise = resolve;
            });
        }
    }
    /**
     * Adds event listeners on the cursor
     * @private
     */
    hookCursorRequest() {
        this.makeNextValuePromise();
        this.cursorRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
            /** @type {IDBCursor} **/
            const cursor = event.target.result;
            this.lastCursor = cursor;
            if (cursor) {
                console.log("[IDB CURSOR] Next value: ", cursor);
                this.resolvePromise(cursor);
            }
            else {
                this.hasNext = false;
                this.resolvePromise(null);
                console.log("[IDB CURSOR] End.");
            }
        };
        this.cursorRequest.onerror = (event) => {
            this.hasNext = false;
            this.rejectPromise(event);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @description Resolves with null or an IDBCursor
     * @returns {Promise<IDBCursor>}
     */
    async next() {
        if (!this.hasNext)
            return null;
        if (this.lastCursor != null) {
            this.makeNextValuePromise();
            this.lastCursor.continue();
        }
        const result = await this.nextValuePromise;
        this.nextValuePromise = null;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Intended usage:

```
    const cursor = new IndexedDBAsyncCursor(this, objectStore.openCursor());
    /** @type {IDBCursor} **/
    var value = null;
    while (value = await cursor.next()) {
        if (predicate(value)) {
            values.push(value.value);
            console.log("[IDB] Found value: ",value.value)
            if (oneOnly)
                break;
        }
        else {
            console.log("[IDB] Value does not match predicate: ",value.value)
        }
    }
```

The problem is this code:

```
    else {
        this.hasNext = false;
        this.resolvePromise(null);
        console.log("[IDB CURSOR] End.");
    }
```

The problem is that `onsuccess` is not called again once the last value is reached. It is simply not called any more, whereas I assumed that it will be called one last time with `null` instead of `IDBCursor`. But no such thing is happening.

How to do this properly?

Comment: I'd start by adding a few more console.log's in the code to see what exactly is happening. for instance, is `this.cursorRequest.onerror` firing?

Comment: No it's not, I'd get promise rejection then. I tried it and even when I put `console.log` in the beginning of the event callbacks, only on popped out.

Comment: you say you'd "get promise rejection" - but your "intended usage" code doesn't handle any promise rejection, so how can you tell you don't get promise rejection :p

Comment: looking at the code, it's almost like you're creating a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A) ... maybe generators will help

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, but generators cannot be async - I already tried that. I put console log everywhere, the callback just isn't called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code as presented works for me in Chrome, but not in Firefox. FYI, here's what I used to drive it:

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase('so');
const open = indexedDB.open('so');
open.onupgradeneeded = e => {
  const db = open.result;
  const s = db.createObjectStore('s');
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    s.put({name: 's' + i, num: i}, i);
  }
};

open.onsuccess = async e => {
  const db = open.result;
  const tx = db.transaction('s');
  const objectStore = tx.objectStore('s')
  const values = [], oneOnly = false;
  const predicate = x => true;

  const cursor = new IndexedDBAsyncCursor(this,objectStore.openCursor());
  /** @type {IDBCursor} **/
  var value = null;
  while (value = await cursor.next()) {
    if (predicate(value)) {
      values.push(value.value);
      console.log("[IDB] Found value: ",value.value)
      if (oneOnly)
        break;
    }
    else {
      console.log("[IDB] Value does not match predicate: ",value.value)
    }
  }
};
```

In Chrome, this logs:

```
[IDB CURSOR] Next value:  IDBCursorWithValue {value: {…}, source: IDBObjectStore, direction: "next", key: 0, primaryKey: 0}
[IDB] Found value:  {name: "s0", num: 0}
[IDB CURSOR] Next value:  IDBCursorWithValue {value: {…}, source: IDBObjectStore, direction: "next", key: 1, primaryKey: 1}
[IDB] Found value:  {name: "s1", num: 1}
[IDB CURSOR] Next value:  IDBCursorWithValue {value: {…}, source: IDBObjectStore, direction: "next", key: 2, primaryKey: 2}
[IDB] Found value:  {name: "s2", num: 2}
[IDB CURSOR] Next value:  IDBCursorWithValue {value: {…}, source: IDBObjectStore, direction: "next", key: 3, primaryKey: 3}
[IDB] Found value:  {name: "s3", num: 3}
[IDB CURSOR] End.
```

The problem is that Chrome and Firefox are inconsistent in when microtasks (i.e. the "then" callbacks for Promises) are executed. Chrome is per-spec, and microtasks are executed within the overall task. Firefox hasn't been fixed yet, and microtasks execute later. More details at https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

As other-Josh alludes, this is a problem here because in Firefox the `continue()` call ends up happening outside the "`success`" event handler, and that's not allowed. You can see by making the following code change to the `async next()` implementation:

```
      try {
        this.lastCursor.continue();
      } catch (ex) { console.error(ex.name, ex.message); }
```

In Firefox this logs: "TransactionInactiveError A request was placed against a transaction which is currently not active, or which is finished." -- because Firefox executes the microtask containing the next call outside the event's task, the transaction is no longer active.

To make this work before the microtask issue is fixed in Firefox, it'll be necessary to restructure your code to call `continue()` directly in the "`success`" handler, regardless of whether or not the next value will be used, which will require reworking how you track/generate promises.

Note that even when the microtask issue is fixed in Firefox the code as written is still unfortunately fragile because doing anything else async inside the `while` loop (i.e. introducing another `await`) would potentially push the `continue()` call out of the task. So if you wanted to e.g. do a `fetch()` while iterating it would break. Doing the `continue()` directly in the "`success`" handler as noted above will make it more robust.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bell! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely confident in this answer, but I don't think you can do per cursor request promises. You can do a promise around the entire cursor walk, but not per iteration.

The reason is kind of complicated but it has something to do with microtasks and and how a transaction times out when it doesn't detect the next request from calling `cursor.continue` in time.

Here is the quote:

> The Problem Indexed DB transactions compose poorly with Promises.
>
> Transactions are defined as having an active flag that is set when the
>   transaction is created, and when an IDB event callback from a source
>   associated with that transaction is run. The active flag is cleared
>   when the task completes i.e. when control returns from script; for
>   example, at the end of the callback. Operations within a transaction
>   (put, get, etc) are only permitted when the flag is true. This implies
>   that you cannot perform operations within a Promise callback, since it
>   is by definition not an IDB event callback. Further, transactions
>   automatically attempt to commit when the flag is cleared and there are
>   no pending requests. This implies that even if the previous
>   restriction was lifted, the transaction would commit before any
>   Promise callback fired. If the active flag mechanism were to be
>   removed entirely, a new commit model would need to be introduced.

Source: https://github.com/inexorabletash/indexeddb-promises

Comment: Thanks. But this is really bad design then. Everyone keeps saying how everything should be async in JS if possible and now this.

Comment: I'm the author of the quoted text. :) Indexed DB predates Promises being added to the web platform. If we had a time machine, things would be different. The pattern here should work, it does just require care and attention. I'll ask some questions above...